# r lubridate: exclude out of the office hours and weekends from the time interval calculations

Tags: r, intervals, lubridate

I would like exclude "out of the office hours" and weekends from the time interval calculations with lubridate.
To be more precise, I have a dataframe with timestamps and would like to calculate the time between two events, which has to exclude out of the office hours (there is a list of office hours for each weekday) and weekends.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  As it stands, I fear your question will quickly be closed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.